# Openssl Handshake failures after thousands of successful connections

Tags: openssl, handshake

I'm having a problem where my server stops accepting connections sometimes
after thousands of successful connections.  I create a global SSL_CTX once,
and then an SSL object for every connection, which I dispose every time.
I'm using version 1.0.2h.

Once the problem occurs, the only way to get around it is to restart the
server, basically recreating the context.  As far as I can tell, the context
"looks" fine, and the so does the session object.  I have watched the
network traffic using wireshark, and every packet looks fine until the
handshake fails.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: There's not much we can do for this question. If I had to hazard a guess (with all other things being equal), then I'd say you have a memory leak in your program. After some running time, the leak surfaces as a hang because there's no virtual memory left.

Comment: Are you freeing the SSL object after each connection with SSL_free()? And any other related objects for that matter. Look at the app size - is it increasing over time?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, there is no memory/threads/handle leaks.  Yes, I'm freeing the SSL object after each connection.I can let it run for hours without issues.  One time I recorded 47k successful sessions before it crapped out.  Other times it might only take a couple of thousands.

Comment: We have the exact same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638696/openssl-server-on-openwrt-router-fails-handshakes-after-time-and-requires-a-rebo  Note, I created a new ticket to share a few more details about our implementation.