# OpenSSL server on OpenWRT router fails handshakes after time and requires a reboot to work again

Tags: ssl, openssl, openwrt, handshake

Okay, I admit this is the weirdest openssl question I have ever seen - but what could be causing a problem that only a REBOOT fixes for OpenSSL?

The basics are that we have a MITM style SSL proxy on an OpenWRT router.  The code works great for hours, and then for some unknown reason (nothing in dmesg or logread) we start getting client handshake failures where openssl just hangs on `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`.

We do use edge triggered epoll but as I said, the code works for HOURS without issue.  Then all of sudden we start getting the `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` condition and when we do, we never get any further information from the client.

From the client, we can run openssl s_client and we get the following:

```
$ openssl s_client -state -CAfile ~/Documents/kdz.pem -servername www.apple.com -connect www.apple.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
depth=1 /C=US/ST=Montana/L=Kalispell/O=kdz/OU=tech/CN=kdzcom/emailAddress=support@kdzcom
verify return:1
depth=0 /1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=California/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=C0806592/C=US/postalCode=95014/ST=California/L=Cupertino/street=1 Infinite Loop/O=Apple Inc./OU=Internet Services for Akamai
verify return:1
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read finished A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read finished A
write:errno=60
```

There is a similar problem mentioned here: [Openssl Handshake failures after thousands of successful connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080905/openssl-handshake-failures-after-thousands-of-successful-connections)

For each connections, we first create a context like this:
`ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method)` (method == SSLv23_server_method())

Then we set these flags: `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_TICKET | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION`

Next we create a random session id: `RAND_bytes(sess_id, IV_SIZE)` and some additional flags:

```
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_SERVER);
SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context(ctx, sess_id, IV_SIZE);
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE, NULL);
```

After each connection we clean up with:

```
SSL_set_shutdown(req->conn.ssl, SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN | SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN);
SSL_free(req->conn.ssl);
SSL_CTX_free(conn->ctx);
```

I am out of ideas and we have spent over a month trying to solve this, please help!!

Comment: Two things come to mind... (1) bad silicon in the router, and (2) running out of memory? For (1), try another router. For (2) the OpenWRT devices I have seen tend to have "just enough" resources but not much more. The routers lack 4 GB or 8 GB of memory, so they are not as tolerant of OpenSSL memory leaks.

Comment: Interesting thoughts.  Regarding #1, we have 100 routers, they all exhibit the same problem.  Regarding #2, its a real possibility.  The routers have one 128MB of ram.  But according to both `free` and `top` we are not out of ram...

Comment: Maybe session caching is taking up too much space as the cache grows over time? Perhaps `SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF` will do the trick. Its on by default for servers, and off by default for clients.

Comment: I will try that now, thanks jww.   Interestingly when I get into this bad state, openssl occasionally returns this error: `1997527396:error:1408A10B:lib(20):func(138):reason(267):NA:0:`

Comment: According to `openssl errstr 0x1408A10B`: `error:1408A10B:SSL routines:func(138):wrong version number`. It really sounds like there's some sort of memory error going on. OpenSSL could be failing on the bad version number, and then [insert your favorite guess leading to bad state].